# Is this pushforward measure also absolutely continous?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I have two random variables, X, and Y, defined on $(M,\mathcal{A})$, and $(N,\mathcal{B})$ with $Y =g(X)$ for some measurable function $g: M\rightarrow N$. X is equipped with a probability measure $\mu_X$ that is absolutely continuous wrt to a $\sigma$-finite measure over M.

Now if in addition I have the push-forward measure of $\mu_Y=g_*\mu_X$ such that $\mu_Y(g(A))=0$ whenever $\mu_X(A)=0$ for any $A\in\mathcal{A}$. Do I have $\mu_Y$ absolutely continuous with respect to some $\sigma$-finite measure on $N$?

I posted and deleted a similar ill-asked question earlier and now I hope this new one makes more sense.

Thank you!

Comment: Without loss of generality take the measure $\xi$ on $M$ with $\mu_X\ll \xi$ to be a finite measure. (This just to ensure that the image measure $\eta$ defined next is $\sigma$-finite.) Define $\eta:=g_*\xi$. Then $\mu_Y\ll\eta$.

Comment: Thank you, John! And we can find such finite measure on $M$ because...?

Comment: A $\sigma$ finite measure can be written as a sum of countably many measures of mass less than one. If you add up the same sequence of measures with summable coefficients $2^{-k}$, you will get an equivalent finite measure.

Comment: I see, thanks Yuval!

Comment: If (and only if) a measure $\nu$ on $M$ is $\sigma$-finite then there is a strictly positive $\mathcal A$-measurable function $\phi$ on $M$ such that $\int_M\phi\,d\nu<\infty$. Now use $\phi$ as density to construct $\xi$ by $\xi(A):=\int_A \phi\,d\nu$ for $A\in\mathcal A$.